# How to get duplicate records after merging results of union all in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle

I have the below query in Oracle

```
select * from (
    select *
                 from (
                          select column1,column2,rownum as rn from table1 a inner join table2 b on (a.column1=b.column1)) where rn>0
    UNION ALL
    select *
                 from (
                          select column1,column2,rownum as rn from table3 a inner join table4 b on (a.column1=b.column1)) where rn>0
) where rownum<=100
```

Now I want to add a condition to see duplicate results such that either by adding a condition before/after merging results.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement ("I want to do a condition check ... by selecting some common columns in them" is too vague and doesn't explain anything); and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment there is no explanation of the desired logic so the question appears unanswerable.

Comment: Does that even work? You've aliased rownum as rn so rownum won't be visible in the outer query?

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge results by `ROWNUM`. There is no inherent order to rows in a table. Anything other than `ROWNUM = 1` or `ROWNUM < n` (when you don't care which row(s) you get, you just want to limit the results) only has meaning within a query block with explicitly ordered input, and that can't be related to any other query block as if it were a key. It's not an attribute of a row. `ROWNUM` is therefore something you should not be using often.

To find duplicate records, simply use `GROUP BY` on the columns you want to look for duplicates on:

```
SELECT column1,column2,COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM table
 GROUP BY column1,column2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you need to see more values other than the grouping keys without having to rejoin back to the table a second time, try an analytical function:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT c.*,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1,column2) cnt
          FROM table)
 WHERE cnt > 1
```